# How can i use for loop in Django to have different titles and texts?

Tags: python, django, loops

Here is my html code. I wanna use for loop to have different texts in different titles. I wanna put each minor sentence in each title, not all 5 sentences under one title!

```
    {% for num in list %}
        <h3>COVID 19 is coming down. {{ num }} </h3>
        {% for sen in text %}
            <div><p>{{ sen }}</p></div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

and here are my views.

```
    def index(request):
        date = dt.datetime.today().date
        _list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
         text = ['This minor text', 'This is major text', 'This is fifth text', 'This is my text', 'This 
                is the last text']
    
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'date': date, 'list': _list, 'text': text, })
```

[image: here is the result]

PROBLEM:
I need one text with one title like:

```
    COVID 19 is coming down. 1
    This minor text
    
    COVID 19 is coming down. 2
    This is major text
    
    .....
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having. Add that in the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from web page, I think you want to have separate text for each title.
You can merge list and text into a single 2D list

HTML

```
{% for num in list %}
    <h3>COVID 19 is coming down. {{ num.0 }} </h3>
    <div><p>{{ sen.1 }}</p></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Python code:

```
def index(request):
    date = dt.datetime.today().date
     _list = [[1,'This minor text'], [2, 'This is major text'], [3,'This is fifth text'], [4,'This is my text'], [5,'This 
            is the last text']]

return render(request, 'index.html', {'date': date, 'list': _list })
```

Comment: added problem with your question, please approve so others can get the problem